# sp_spaceused reveals 0 rows but 72 KB of reserved space

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssms

When I run `sp_spaceused dummybizo` I get the following results:

```
name        rows    reserved    data    index_size  unused
dummybizo   0       72 KB       8 KB    8 KB        56 KB
```

I am expecting the following results:

```
name        rows    reserved    data    index_size  unused
dummybizo   0       0 KB        0 KB    0 KB        0 KB
```

What is causing the reserved memory?

I have already tried to force a ghost record clean up with `alter table dummybizo rebuild;` but it doesn't change the results. I've also tried `truncate table dummybizo` but it doesn't do anything to these stats. I also note that `select * from dummybizo with (nolock)` doesn't reveal any hidden records.

What should I try next? I would like to set up the table such that the stats read `0   0 KB   0 KB   0 KB   0 KB`

Comment: the number 72 sounds like an IAM page and a uniform extent to me. Perhaps LOB pages? I would start by using sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations to see what type of pages there are, and then also determine what table type (clustered, heap, clustered columnstore) along with indexes, triggers and other special features you have. Based on that I would fire up my favourite search engine and start searching. I did a quick search for below and got some promising hits, but we a thin on information here. remove LOB pages SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

Likely, there is an [IAM page](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-iam-pages-iam-chains-and-allocation-units/) and [extent](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-an-extent/) reserved for this table. `TRUNCATE TABLE` will remove these. When all data is just deleted, a bare minimum structure will still exist for the table.

Have a demo!

```
--Setup
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.welcometable
CREATE TABLE dbo.welcometable
(ID INT)

EXEC sp_spaceused 'dbo.welcometable'
--all 0s

-----------------------------------------------------
--Let's see what spaceused looks like when there's data
INSERT dbo.welcometable
VALUES (1)

EXEC sp_spaceused 'dbo.welcometable'
--72KB reserved, 8KB data, 8KB index, 56KB unused

-----------------------------------------------------
--Now what if we delete?
DELETE FROM dbo.welcometable

EXEC sp_spaceused 'dbo.welcometable'
--72KB reserved, 8KB data, 8KB index, 56KB unused

-----------------------------------------------------
--What if we truncate?
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.welcometable

EXEC sp_spaceused 'dbo.welcometable'
--all 0s
--success!
```

If you want to actually see the pages and where they are, use this:

```
SELECT page_type_desc, allocated_page_page_id, is_allocated
FROM sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations(DB_ID(),OBJECT_ID('dbo.welcometable'),NULL,NULL,'DETAILED')
```

This shows one IAM page and one reserved extent for me, even when all rows have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me IAM pages are still allocated. To find a solution to this or at least better understanding of this problem I would start by searching on the web and also creating my own copy of sp_spaceused procedure with a different name in the user database and debugging it.